# Optimal upload bandwidth for Sharepoint Online?

Tags: file-upload

Looking for some advice on the optimal upload speed for our internet connection now that we've moved to Sharepoint Online. We're a small business (15 users) working with mostly Word, Excel, PDF, and JPG files- nothing unique or fancy. Curious if there's an optimal upload speed to facilitate the smoothest function of OneDrive syncing Sharepoint folders to each users Windows Explorer. Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Optimal will be measuring your current usage and estimating if that is enough. There is no one size fits all number, regardless of the number of people in the office.

Answer (score 0):

Like Trevor already wrote, there is no "Magic number". It all depents on your workload in general and how you'll use SharePoint Online in combination with OneDrive. In case you have a high count on big documents (big means more than just a few Megabytes), you'll probably need more than the average customer.
If you just use it from time to time and sync your OneDrive from time to time, you won't even feel any difference in your everyday work.

To get a feeling for what you need, simply monitor your local network (and your WAN connection as well) you're using right now for the over all load. If you see only some peaks in WAN, you should be fine with the current state.